# EXC_BAD_ACCESS using self.performSelector

Tags: swift, swift-playground, performselector

This is a simple academic not real code.

I want to run print method using performSelector function. But If I run this code in playground, throws an exception:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).

Code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

@objc(Foo)
class Foo: NSObject {

    func timer() {
        self.performSelector( #selector(Foo.print))
    }

    @objc func print() {
        NSLog("print")
    }
}

let instance = Foo()
instance.timer()     // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Strange, it crashes in a Playground but it works in a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your `Foo.print()` to something like this:

```
    @objc func print() -> AnyObject? {
        NSLog("print")
        return nil
    }
```

I believe the code runs in the Playground too.

`performSelector`s return type is not `Void`.

[- performSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:)

> ```
> func performSelector(_ aSelector: Selector) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>!
> ```

So, Playground tries to get the result value to display. Which in fact is not returned.

Comment: I don't think so, since we're not printing the result of `performSelector`, we're printing the result of `timer` which is `Void`.

Comment: @JAL, it's not how the Playground treats each expression. Any facts supporting your hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, change the class to not inherit from `NSObject` and change `timer()` to `(self as AnyObject).performSelector(#selector(Foo.print))`.  There's no crash and the line evaluates to `nil` in the Playground.

Comment: @EricD, it's related to what sort of machine code Swift generates. A returned value is set to a CPU register, for example RAX in x64. For `Void` methods, Swift does not generate codes to modify RAX. So, in some cases it may be nil, in other cases it may contain some garbage, which may cause crash when used as a pointer. Someone can find a "lucky sequence", which accidentally set 0 to RAX and keeps the value, but it cannot be guaranteed. So, in your test code, the value set in RAX (which may be nil or may not be nil) is silently discarded, as the returned value is not used.

Comment: @JAL, the above comment of mine is being also an answer for you.

Comment: @OOPer Thanks for the clear explanation!  So you're saying I just got a "lucky sequence?"

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution which does not require a change in function signature:

```
class Foo {

    func timer() {
        (self as AnyObject).performSelector(#selector(Foo.print))
    }

    @objc func print() {
        NSLog("print")
    }
}

let instance = Foo()
instance.timer()
```

Might have to do with Objective-C API bridging, still investigating...